# default errorhandler for wildfly 8 logging mechanism

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am migrating a project from JBoss 4.2.3 to Wildfly 9. I am using default jboss-logging mechanism

We had errorHandler for every appender in jboss-log4j.xml

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
</appender>
```

What is the equivalent of errorHandler in jboss own logging mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a custom error handler in logging subsystem on WildFly. By default though an [`OnlyOnceErrorHandler`](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/2.0.0.Final/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/ExtHandler.java#L46) is used.